# "Our subconscious" or "our subconsciousness"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Example:

> There are many hidden things in the unreachable depth of our
>   subconscious/subconsciousness.

What's the most common choice? Is the first option ungrammatical?

Comment: It's not a matter of grammar (both are fine on that score). Simply that in practice we usually just use ***subconscious*** as a noun in contexts like this. The relevant definition for ***subconsciousness*** in OED is simply ***= SUBCONSCIOUS***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a subtle difference between the two. Both of them are nouns, in addition to the word `subconscious` in the adjective form.

> **[Subconscious<sup>1</sup> (adj.)](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/subconscious_1)**: feelings, desires etc are hidden in your mind and affect your behaviour, but you do not know that you
>   have them: [BrEn] *a subconscious fear of failure*

---

> **[Subconscious<sup>2</sup> (n.)](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/subconscious_2)**: the part of your mind that has thoughts and feelings you do not know about. [= unconscious]: *anger buried deep in the subconscious*

As you can notice, ***subconscious*** refers to *a part of your brain*, as some ***thing***, where ***subconsciousness*** refers to ***an state of being***. So your sentence would sound more grammatical with the former choice.

I also noticed that even subscription-only LDOCE does not have an entry for *subconsciousness*, where it mentions *unconsciousness*.

Checking [Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=subconsciousness%2Cunconsciousness%2Csubconscious%2C%20unconscious&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csubconsciousness%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunconsciousness%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csubconscious%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunconscious%3B%2Cc0), I'm being convinced that nowadays *unconsciousness* is more common than *subconscious*, however that won't affect your question or the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

As FumbleFingers observes, both *subconscious* and *subconsciousness* can be nouns (*subconscious* can also be an adjective), so there is nothing to choose grammatically between the two. Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary defines the noun form of *subconscious* as follows:

> **subconscious** *n* (1886) the mental activities just below the threshold of consciousness.

The dictionary doesn't explicitly define *subconsciousness*, but if we interpret it as meaning simply the state associated with the adjective *subconscious* (beneath which the word *subconsciousness* appears in the Eleventh Collegiate), we get this definition:

> **subconsciousness** *n* [the state of] existing in the mind but not [being] immediately available to consciousness.

The two definitions seem distinctly different to me, though I know practically nothing, consciously or subconsciously, about this area of science. Nevertheless, I suspect that *subconscious* (the mental activities) is a better match in the original example than *subconsciousness* (the state of existing but not being accessible to consciousness).

Your unease about using the word *subconscious* as a noun may stem from the fact that it is derived from the identically spelled adjective, which Merriam-Webster's dates to circa 1834.

The first instance of a freestanding occurrence of "the subconscious" in a Google Books search occurs in William R. Newbold, "[Suggestibility, Automatism, and Kindred](http://books.google.com/books?id=rpxJAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA375&lpg=PA375&dq=%22William+Romaine+Newbold%22+%22Conception+of+the+Subconscious%22&source=bl&ots=0swXrxkxkD&sig=km-3sLk7oNXChFhu3gEtjoT2dlY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=L7DaU66YKqq1iQLx34CgBA&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=subconscious&f=false)" in *Appleton's Popular Science Monthly* (January 1896), as a section head:

> II. The Properties of Mental States.—The Conception of the Subconscious.

Over the next three years, *Popular Science* published several articles that discussed "the subconscious," but most other publications of the time used the term "the subconscious" only as part of a longer phrase, "the subconscious mind."

Particularly noteworthy in this regard is an article by Clark Bell titled “[The Sub-conscious Mind. Sub-liminal Consciousness](http://books.google.com/books?id=YRcCAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA136&dq=%22subconscious+mind%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=U5XaU_H9E5CIogSLu4L4Cw&ved=0CFwQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q&f=false),” in *The Medico-Legal Journal* (1897). This article quotes in full letters sent to the author by 15 eminent psychologists (including William James) in response to the author's request for their views on the notion of "the sub-conscious mind"; in their letters, none of the responding psychologists use *subconscious* (or *sub-conscious*) as a noun.

It thus appears that psychologists in the late 1800s were much more willing to use *subconscious* as an adjective (couple with the noun *mind*) than as a noun standing on its own. Part of this preference may simply reflect the fact that "the conscious Mind" appears as early as 1718 (in [*The Complete Art of Poetry*](http://books.google.com/books?id=dbgnAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA223&dq=%22the+conscious+mind%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1rTaU4WiIqryiwKAr4D4Bg&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22the%20conscious%20mind%22&f=false) by Charles Gildon), whereas "the conscious as a way of identifying the mindful correlative of "the subconscious" was unknown and has never broadly caught on).

As for whether *subconscious* (as a noun) or *subconsciousness* is more common, a standard [Ngram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+conscious+mind%2Cthe+subconscious+mind%2Csubconsciousness%2Cthe+subconscious&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20conscious%20mind%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20subconscious%20mind%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csubconsciousness%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20subconscious%3B%2Cc0) can't tell us much, since it doesn't let us isolate "the unconscious" as a stand-alone noun phrase from "the subconscious X" where *subconscious* is an adjective and X is one or another noun. An Ngram graph does indicate, however, that *subconsciousness* was not more popular than "the subconscious mind" during the second half of the twentieth century and that the undifferentiated matches for "the subconscious" (comprising instances of *subconscious* as an adjective and *subconscious* as a noun were considerably more common than the matches for *subconsciousness*:

[image]

In any event, *subconscious* as a noun has been in use for more than a century, and current usage shows no sign of dropping it in favor of either "the subconscious mind" or *subconsciousness*.